# Alter 'tags to run' during execution

Tags: cucumber

Lets say I have something like this

```
@regression @monthly @A
Scenario:A

@regression @B
Scenario:B

@regression
Scenario:General
```

I run my tests using a runner that calls cucumber tests like

```
cucumber --tags @regression TEST_PARAM1=something
```

During particular cases (based on TEST_PARAM1 value) I want to skip "Scenario:A or Scenario:B", dynamically.

Can I somehow use 'before' hook (or something else) to dynamically add @A or @B tag to the skip list based over a condition?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to possible with the current version of Cucumber. It doesn't have a public, non-deprecated API for mutating the list of tags passed on the command-line. You can only do a wrapper script that invokes `cucumber` and dynamically chooses tags while doing so. Or, you can [embed Ruby in the `cucumber.yml` file](https://github.com/vcr/vcr/blob/2cca59163b2e19d5c29e8650ae34cd1d731a9e39/cucumber.yml).

Related: [Is it possible to skip a scenario with Cucumber-JVM at run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16037999/11687)