# How to skip the execution of a scenario in cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have to check if the previous scenario has executed completely and if it fails I need to skip next Scenario, is it possible?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037999/is-it-possible-to-skip-a-scenario-with-cucumber-jvm-at-run-time

Answer (score 0):

Afaik this is not possible. In general, Scenarios should be independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [gherkin with qaf](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) where you can either set dependencies (which is not preferable but supported with qaf bdd) or adding testng method invocation listener and skip scenario on condition in before invocation method.